# Android REST API client that allows file attachments for a http POST

Tags: android, rest, http

Is anybody aware of an Android app that acts as a REST API client and allows attaching files?  I'm looking to do the equivalent of this in Postman, but from an Android device:

[image]

I've tried "REST Client for Android" and "HTTP Client" available on Google Play, but these only seem to allow text in the body, not file attachments.  Can anybody advise on options for this for Android currently ??

Answer (score 0):

https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

pls find above link for retrofit api mostly used restapi.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpURLConnection class to upload image on server.

```
String urlStr= "url link";
String response;
boolean isGetMethod = false;
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n", twoHyphens = "--", boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        File file;
        int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if (!isGetMethod) {

                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());

                file = new File("image file path");
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();
            }

            if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(inputLine);
                }
                response = builder.toString();
                bufferedReader.close();
            } else
                return response;

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
    }
}
```